# How to calculate how much data a Core 2 duo E8 can write to the RAM per second?

Tags: cpu, assembly, ram, sdram, intel

I'd like to know how exactly I could calculate how much data the Core 2 duo E8 can write to the RAM per second, given that it is not overclocked and the RAM is 333MHz-DDR3?

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be: which RAM? Do you mean one of the L1/L2 caches (those are pretty quick), L3 or worser still: memory RAM?

Possibly of use:
https://panthema.net/2013/pmbw/results.html

You also [grab the utility here](https://panthema.net/2013/pmbw/) and run it yourself.

Notice the enormous differences between "cache" and RAM bandwidths. Such differences also translate to random access latency as well.
Modern high-performance computing is all about hitting that cache as efficiently as possible, because going down in caches or back to main memory is a massive slowdown.

Comment: 333MHz DDR3 SDRAM as mentioned in the question. But I guess the CPU loads the instructions form the RAM and then stores it in the cache to run it repeatedly.